# Fenchel conjugate of least squares in a Banach case

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I can't wrap my head around this question: let $\mathcal{X}$ be a Banach space, let $\mathcal{X}^*$ be its dual and $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space (such as $L^2$). Define the linear mapping $\Phi : \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{H}$ and the observation $y \in \mathcal{H}$.
Then, for all $x \in \mathcal{X}$

$$ f(x) = || y - \Phi x ||_\mathcal{H}^2 $$

Is there a close form of the Fenchel conjugate of $f$, defined for all $x^* \in \mathcal{X}^*$ by:

$$ f^*(x^*) = \sup_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \langle x, x^*\rangle  - f(x) $$

I tried Fermat rule but this does not reach any conclusive results.

Comment: unless you suppose $\Phi$ invertible which kind of lack some style...

Comment: Is $\phi$ bounded? Then you could try to calculate the Fréchet-derivative of $\langle x,x^*\rangle-f(x)$ and determine its zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

(Very) partial answer (too long for a comment): If ${\cal X, X^*, H}$ are all equal to $\mathbb R^n$ and, for simplicity $y=0$ and $\Phi$ is the identity. Then $f(x)=||x||^2$ is convex and the supremum is attained for $x$ satsifying
$$
0=x^*_i-\partial_if(x)=x^*_i-2x_i\quad\forall i=1,...,n\,.
$$
Therefore, plugging $x=x^*/2$ into $\langle x,x^*\rangle-f(x)$ gives
$$
f^*(x^*)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(x^*_i)^2}{2}-f(x^*/2)=\frac{||x^*||}{2}-\frac{||x^*||}{4}=\frac{||x^*||}{4}\,.
$$